# Need to remove the tab which is below the contents section in active report6

Tags: activereports

I'm facing the problem in active report viewer as i want to hide the controls *****table of contents and thumbnail view***** of pages which you can find in the table of contents section in report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the TableofContents, you need to set the Viewer.TableOfContents' '[Visible](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports.Viewer6~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Viewer.TableOfContentsObject~Visible.html)' property to False.

Regards,
Mohita